# how do I make it clear when applying for a job that I'm willing and able to relocate at very short notice?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, recruitment

I've previously mentioned that I was considering looking for new jobs for x and y (not relevant to this question) reasons.

I'm applying for jobs in State A since I used to live there, and I can very well move over there whenever I feel like. I'm currently located 600 miles from my old home/location. And although I'm more than willing to move and I plan to mention it in a cover letter or additional comments inside the applications, I still wonder if my current location is something that would discourage recruiters from even considering me as a potential employee.

Comment: Suggest you retitle this as the answer to the title question is very different from what you're actually asking.

Comment: Sorry both make sense to me, I still struggle from time to time since English is not my first language, if you could suggest me how to reword it to make it clearer I would appreciate it @Lilienthal

Comment: In the title you ask if your current location is important for recruiters: it always is. In the body of your post you're actually asking whether it will harm your chances if you're applying to far away jobs even though you mention your willingness to relocate. We typically only want one central question per post on this site. A better version of the second question may be "*how do I make it clear when applying for a job that I'm willing and able to relocate at very short notice?*".

Comment: I live about 2 hours from a major city, and most recruiters I speak with ask me if I'm willing to relocate.  If you get a conversation going with the recruiter, it will likely come up, and they will normally be able to tell you if the company offers relocation assistance or not as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I make it clear when applying for a job that I'm willing and
>   able to relocate

I'd argue that you don't. Every word in a tightly-wrapped cover letter and resume is precious space that you could be using to impress the recruiter. I'm pretty confident that if you live in **A** and are applying for a job in **B**, the potential employer assumes that you realize that you're not applying for a local job. It's 2016 and we're well into the Age of the Internet; employers aren't expecting that you found out about this position in your local newspaper.

Your willingness to relocate is *a given* if you're applying for a job that's not local. It's almost like writing on your resume,

"*Will work for money.*"

Isn't that the point of applying for a job to begin with?

So the employer assumes that you're willing to relocate for the job that you're applying for, so that leaves us with,

> relocate at very short notice?

In my experience, interested companies will usually say in the first email or phone call something like,

"*As you may know, this job is located in Vermont. If offered a position, how soon would you be able to relocate?*"

The first thing to note is their assumption of your willingness to relocate (which ties into the first part of this answer). The second thing to pay attention to is the fact that *if they're interested, they'll ask*. Now you have the opportunity to express how quickly you can relocate. If they don't ask you here, they *will* ask you eventually but even if you could move across the galaxy in two days, that's not going to be the deciding factor on a job offer. This is why I'm suggesting that you don't waste your CV or resume space on this. Good luck!

*NOTE: If you were **unwilling** to relocate or couldn't relocate within a reasonable amount of time, then that's probably something you'd want to mention on a CV. It'll knock your odds of employment down but it'll filter out the companies that are not looking to hire someone in such a position, thus saving them and you time in the process. There's no point in getting to the interview stage, or any stage for that matter, just to find out that the company and you are incompatible.*

Answer (score 3):

If you say you are willing to relocate for the job, where you are now is mostly not an issue except that it makes in-person interviews more of a pain for all concerned.

Comment: I've thought about that, and also any other processes that involve me being physically present to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a few hundred miles within the same company, I can't see recruiters seeing that as not worth trying to do business with you.  I think that local people would have an advantage in reduced risk associated with relocation but that advantage isn't huge.

That said once you start scaling up to international relocation, companies would expect to pay your moving costs and this isn't cheap and there may be assumptions that visas will be required so you may be looking at a significant disadvantage as an applicant.

Comment: Yeah I basically struggled with that last year when looking for a job, I just thought that maybe with a year of experience under my belt I would be a bit more attractive as a potential employee

Comment: Better to save the money and gain the experience then move when you can afford to relocate with reasonable savings then search for a job in the new country.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you clarify the language in your cover letter that you are willing to relocate to the new location **at your own expense** (if you haven't).  That will be a flag to recruiters that you're not fishing for a big signing bonus to get you moved.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than a full answer and I also disagree with your assessment. Some companies offer relocation bonuses, some don't. There's no need for the candidate to specify something that's always assumed, especially if it makes you look desperate.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me, even though it's short.  It's succinct.  Additionally, it most certainly is not always assumed. Depending on what you do and your experience level, as well as your demand, paid relocation is very common, and at a certain level, it's often expected.